# Selenium Webdriver Performance for Parallel tests with Chrome Driver on Windows 10 vs Ubuntu Linux and local vs cloud

Tags: linux, windows, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have some parallel Selenium Webdriver tests with long series of steps and some threads running on windows 10 via chrome driver (headless).

Any pointers on whether the tests would run faster on a Ubuntu Linux?

To make things even faster would you suggest deploying on google cloud /AWS? 
If yes, which OS/Cloud platform combination performs the best versus local server?

My local server has Intel Core i5/Windows 10/16 GB RAM/SSD

Comment: Suggested one edit, you need to format your question to make them more readable.. welcome to SO

Answer (score 0):

Accoding to the article "[4 Reasons to use Linux Agents vs Windows Agents](https://www.machmetrics.com/speed-blog/4-reasons-to-use-linux-agents-vs-windows-agents-webpagetest-amis/)" it seems to be a good idea to use Linux and Amazon EC2.

The major advantage of using a cloud solution like EC2 is the availability of multiple instances. You can setup your own Selenium grid that will outperform you local server. Set up a grid hub and begin with two instances. Add more instances until your runtime improvement is marginal. Then remove the last instance and use that configuration.